# No me aparece la opción de crear la carpeta assets

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Antes si salía la opción de crear la carpeta assets, ya no.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para crear la carpeta `/assets` es necesario crearla dando botòn derecho al proyecto (No tratar desde el menù principal de Android Studio) e ir a la secuencia `New` - `Folder` - `Assets Folder`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]